# Hiding parent divs in Jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, html

I am having a simple div structure ( see below ). All I am trying to do is when the div id "interviewer-Button" is clicked the following div's should appear and when the div id "elt" is clicked divs from id "parent0" till the end should hide.

The display part works fine. However, when I try to hide, it just does NOT hide. When i click on the div id "elt" the alert message "hh" (see below) gets thrown!! Weird. Any help on how to hide this?

```
<div id = "interviewer-Button">
   Interviewer
   <div id = "parent0">
         Viv
          <div id = "parent1">
                Parent
                <div id = "elt">
                     Close
                 </div>

          </div>                                        
    </div>                                                              
</div>    


<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#parent0").hide();   
    $("#interviewer-Button").click(function() { alert("hh");$("#parent0").show(); });
    $("#elt").click( function () {
            $(this).parent().parent().hide();
         });                
     });
</script>
```

Answer (score 26):

You need to stop propagation of the click event in the handler for the inner element.  Without that the handler for the parent will also be invoked.  See the [jQuery event object](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/jQuery.Event) for more info.

```
$("#elt").click( function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(this).parent().parent().hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

n/aUsed a combination of the above. Thanks to both members for their answers. great help.

```
            jQuery(function ($) {
                $('.coffee-strength p span').each(function () {
                    var string = $.trim($(this).text());
                    if(string!="22"){
                        $(this).html('<img src="/images/' + string + '.png" alt="' + string + '" />');
                    }else{
                        $(this).parent().parent().hide();    
                    }
                    });

            });

            </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also take advantage of event propagation and attach just one event:

```
$(function() {
  $("#parent0").hide(); 
  $("#interviewer-Button").on('click', function(e){
    $(this).find('#parent0').toggle(e.target.id !== 'elt');
  });
});
```