# Multiple Jquery div toggle works in Firefox, not in Safari or Opera?

Tags: jquery, performance, html, toggle

this code works in Firefox, but not in Safari or Opera. Not sure about IE since I'm on a mac. Any idea why? I am a newb, and this is just a code I found and edited to my needs:

```
<div id = "button">Bryllup
    <div id="parent1">
        shown text
        <div id ="parent11">
            <div id = "elt1">
                Close
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#parent1").hide();       
    $("#button").click(function() {$("#parent1").show(); });
    $("#elt1").click( function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        $(this).parent().parent().hide();
    });
});
</script>
```

I found the code in this post on this website:
[Hiding parent divs in Jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1028894/hiding-parent-divs-in-jquery)

Comment: Works exactly the same for me in Chrome, Firefox, Opera and Safari. What errors are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to work here in Chrome, Safari and Opera (on Windows Vista) when I put it [in this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/hRfUa/).  Can you try that jsFiddle yourself?  This type of situation (where your code works fine for us) usually means that there's something else wrong with your page that you aren't showing us or you've left out something that causes an error when you condensed the code for posting here.

- What else is going on in your page?
- Have you looked in the debug console to see if any errors are reported?
- When you say it doesn't work, what exactly do you observe?