# Jquery - can't hide parent div

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a table, that has a div in the cell, When I click on the row it shows a div that is a absolute positioned div(order-details) inside the first cell div. When I click on the dismiss div, I want to hide the parent (order-details) div again.. It won't hide it.

I've also made a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JESEH/)

```
<table>
    <tr class="order-row">
        <td>
            <div class="dummy-detail-position">
                <div class="order-details">
                    <div class="dismiss">X</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
     <tr class="order-row">
        <td>
            <div class="dummy-detail-position">
                <div class="order-details">
                    <div class="dismiss">X</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
     <tr class="order-row">
        <td>
            <div class="dummy-detail-position">
                <div class="order-details">
                    <div class="dismiss">X</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

This is my JS

```
<script>
$(document).on('click','.order-row',function() { 
        var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
        $(this).find('.order-details').show();
})

$(document).on('click','.dismiss',function() { 
    alert($(this).parent().parent().html());
    $(this).parent().parent().find('.order-details').hide();

});
</script>
```

Comment: Try just $(this).parent().hide();

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is because of event propagation

```
$(document).on('click','.order-row',function() { 
    var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
    $(this).find('.order-details').show();
})

$(document).on('click','.dismiss',function(e) { 
    e.stopPropagation()
    $(this).closest('.order-details').hide();    
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/EAVbe/)

Since `order-now` is an ancestor of `dismiss`, the `order-now` handler will get triggered after the `dismiss` handler, which will again display the `order-details` element

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/EAVbe/2/)

Comment: Of course!! thank you I just found this too http://stackoverflow.com/a/1028924/994113   Will accept.