# Hide parent DIV with jQuery

Tags: jquery

How do I hide a parent div if a class is displayed?

My Attempt:

HTML:

```
<div>
  this content should be hidden. 
  <div class="hide-parent"></div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("hide-parent").parent().hide();
});
</script>
```

Same idea as this, but mine doesn't work:
[Hiding parent divs in Jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1028894/hiding-parent-divs-in-jquery)

http://jsfiddle.net/uydpesxa/ example here:

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to put a period in front of `hide-parent` since it is a class name selector.

Fixed code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".hide-parent").parent().hide();
});
</script>
```

Also, in your fiddle, you forgot to pick "jQuery" from the list of libraries.

See fixed fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/uydpesxa/6/

The above code will hide the parent element if the `hide-parent` element is *present* in the DOM.

To answer the other part of your question, *if a class is displayed* (which I interpret as meaning "not hidden"):

You can write the code to see if the element with that class is visible. One easy way is to use `:visible` in the selector, and another is to use the `is()` function.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  // for each visible "hide-parent" elem, hide its parent elem.

  // option A, using :visible pseudo-selector
  // $(".hide-parent:visible").parent().hide();

  // or.. option B, using is(); perhaps a bit more maintainable / understandable
  $(".hide-parent").each(function () {
      if ($(this).is(":visible")) {
          $(this).parent().hide();
      }
  });
});
</script>
```

See Fiddle for hiding parent when content hidden: http://jsfiddle.net/uydpesxa/7/